# GSON toJson() method returns null for a POJO

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

This is my POJO class

```
public class ResourceRecord {

    public ResourceRecord() {}

    public String name;
    public Integer ttl;
    public String type;
    public String rr;

    @SerializedName("class")
    public String dnsClass;

}
```

And this the serialisation:

```
ResourceRecord rr = new ResourceRecord() {
    {
        name = "8.8.8.8";
        dnsClass = "IN";
        ttl = 600;
        rr = "0431shangmao.com.";
        type = "A";
    }
};

String rrStr = new Gson().toJson(rr);
```

Apparently, `rrStr` gets `null`. Why?

I tried annotating the fields with `@Expose` but the result stayed the same.

**UPDATE:** 
I changed to constructing to:

```
ResourceRecord rr = new ResourceRecord("8.8.8.8", 900,"A","1.dnstest.netshade.net.", "IN");
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because you were creating anonymous innerclass of `ResourceRecord` when you instantiate using curly braces:

```
ResourceRecord rr = new ResourceRecord() {
      {
          name = "8.8.8.8";
          dnsClass = "IN";
          ttl = 600;
          rr = "0431shangmao.com.";
          type = "A";
      }
  };
```

And Gson doesn't support serializing anonymous subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
 String json = gson.toJson(obj);`

obj is the object of pojo class